# method to return subset of a list of elements with some predefined properties?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A` with elements representing relations of the form `["item1", "relationstype" ,"item2"]`.

I want to write a function which return a list of all "relationstype" such that if `["item1", "relationstype" ,"item2"]` is in A, then `["item2", "relationstype" ,"item1"]` is also in A.

For rexample, if `A=[["item1", "relationstype1" ,"item2"],["item3", "relationstype2" ,"item2"],["item2", "relationstype1" ,"item1"],["item2", "relationstype2" ,"item3"],["item3", "relationstype2" ,"item4"]]`, then the method should return `["relationstype1"]`.

this is what I tried:

```
def find_symmetric_realations(A):
    relation_dict = {}
    symmetric_realations = set()
    for elem in A:
        relationstype = elem[1]
        if relationstype not in relation_dict:
            relation_dict[relationstype] = [(elem[0], elem[2])] # pout relation in dic
        else:
            if (elem[2],elem[0]) in relation_dict[relationstype]:
                continue
            else:
                relation_dict[relationstype].append((elem[0], elem[2]))
    # print(relation_dict[list(relation_dict.keys())[0]])
    for elem in relation_dict:
        if all((b,a) in relation_dict[elem] for (a,b) in relation_dict[elem]):
            symmetric_realations.add(elem)
    return list(symmetric_realations)
```

Comment: So you want to find all symmetric relations? A natural approach might be to construct a dictionary of dictionaries where the outer dictionary is keyed by the relations and the inner dictionaries are keyed by the items.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'd be really interested to see how you'd approach that...

Comment: If i understand him correctly its similar to my posted answer? Albeit I don't have an inner dictionary but a list of tuples. Its still the same logic I believe?

Comment: @DaniMesejo raised an interesting question, what should be the output for `A = [["item1", "relationstype1", "item2"],["item3", "relationstype2", "item2"],["item2", "relationstype1", "item1"], ["item3", "relationstype1", "item1"]]`? is `["relationship1"]` still valid, or should the fact that `["item1", "relationstype1", "item3"]` is not in `A` but `["item3", "relationstype1", "item1"]` is mean that the output should be empty even though there is a pair `["item1", "relationstype1", "item2"]` and `["item2", "relationstype1", "item1"]`?

Comment: "A relation R over set A is symmetric if for all x, y from A the following is true: if (x,y) is in R, then (y,x) is in R." @Nick

Comment: @abhinonymous indeed, that is what OP is looking for, but was not clear from the original question. Note that your code also fails for the example in my comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Based on comments and edits to the question, the original answer was incorrect as it only considered if there was *a* matching pair for a given relationship, rather than requiring *all* elements for that relationship to have a matching pair. This function solves that problem:

```
def symmetric_relationships(A):
    A = set(tuple(e) for e in A)
    rels = set(r for (_, r, _) in A)
    return [r for r in rels if all((i2, rel, i1) in A for (i1, rel, i2) in A if rel == r)]
```

For example:

```
A = [
     ["item1", "relationstype1", "item2"],
     ["item3", "relationstype2", "item2"],
     ["item2", "relationstype1", "item1"]
     ]

print(symmetric_relationships(A))
A.append(["item3", "relationstype1", "item1"])
print(symmetric_relationships(A))
A.append(["item2", "relationstype2", "item3"])
print(symmetric_relationships(A))
A.append(["item1", "relationstype1", "item3"])
print(symmetric_relationships(A))
```

Output:

```
['relationstype1']
[]
['relationstype2']
['relationstype1', 'relationstype2']
```

**Original Answer**

You can brute-force this with a list comprehension:

```
r = [r for i1, r, i2 in A if [i2, r, i1] in A]
```

this will give

```
['relationstype1', 'relationstype1']
```

which you can convert to a unique-valued list with

```
list(set(r))
```

If `item1` is never exactly the same as `item2` you can also skip the last step by adding an `i1 < i2` test to the list comprehension:

```
r = [r for i1, r, i2 in A if [i2, r, i1] in A and i1 < i2]
```

Performance wise you can probably improve it by converting `A` to a set (after first converting it to tuples):

```
A = set(tuple (e) for e in A)
r = [r for i1, r, i2 in A if (i2, r, i1) in A and i1 < i2]
```

Comment: Why not `r = [r for i1, r, i2 in A if (i2, r, i1) in set(A)]` to make it less brute-forcish? You only need to convert A to tuples first: `A = tuple((tuple (e) for e in A))`

Comment: `in set(...)` takes constant time while `in list(...)` is O(n).

Comment: So this code returns a relation if there is one pair that is symmetric, but we need to have all pair that is symmetric.

Comment: @user42493 sorry, that wasn't clear from your original question. I've updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: @DaniMesejo it seems your interpretation was correct. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following function finds symmetric relations in your list:

```
def find_symmetric_realations(A):
    relation_dict = {}
    symmetric_realations = set()

    for elem in A:
        relationstype = elem[1]
        if relationstype not in relation_dict:
            relation_dict[relationstype] = [(elem[0], elem[2])]
        else:
            if (elem[2],elem[0]) in relation_dict[relationstype]:
                symmetric_realations.add(relationstype)
            else:
                relation_dict[relationstype].append((elem[0], elem[2]))

    return symmetric_realations
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index,list1 in enumerate(A):
    for list2 in A[index:]:
        check =  all(item in list1 for item in list2)
        if check==True and list1!=list2:
            print(list1[1])
```

**Explanation:** On looping over enumerate(A), we get index & single lists. 'check' stores True if all elements of list1 are in list2(from 2nd loop). If check==true but list1 isn't equal to list2, print the middle value i.e the relationship